# A word meaning an "indifferent resignation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title says, I'm looking for a word that is similar to resignation, but conveys a feeling of indifference.
For example:

> Although I have severe myopia, I've lived with it all my life and have therefore [word here] myself to the condition.

Thanks very much to anybody who can answer this.

Comment: Ivan, you mean that you care LESS about the condition than if you were merely "resigned"? If I could wave a magic wand and cure your myopia, you would say, "Don't bother"? I find that odd, as a myopic-presbyopic-astigmatic myself.

Comment: OP could say he [has inured himself](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+inured+himself%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but it's much more common to say he [has become inured](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+become+inured%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But you can't really be simultaneously *indifferent* and *resigned*, since the latter always implies ***reluctant*** acceptance of a [bad] situation you *would* like to be different (so you *must* "care" at least a bit).

Comment: Not a word, you could say "it is what it is". That generally means you know there is a problem, but you don't want to address it or resolve it.

Comment: @DavidPugh Sorry, it was a little unclear. Of course, if there was a 'magic' cure for my myopia (which I chose an example since I am myopic of course) I'd take it, but I wouldn't go through any real effort to fix it (LASIK, LASEK, etc, although I'm too far gone and still getting worse for those to be effective or even a good idea) aside from the regular eyewear replacement.

Comment: The thought of a laser operation on my eyes scares the bejeezus out of me, so I guess I empathise.

Comment: @DavidPugh The worst part in my opinion is that they hold your eyes open with some sort of speculum contraption. The laser is bad, but I think this takes the biscuit.

Comment: Yet another option is _reconciled_, as in either "Although I have severe myopia, I've lived with it all my life and have therefore reconciled myself to the condition" or "Although I have severe myopia, I have lived with it all my life and am now reconciled to the condition." Here _reconciled_ simply means "come to terms with," so it can apply to situations involving various feelings about the thing being accepted, but "indifferent resignation" is certainly among those possibilities.

Comment: What about 'adaptation' to the condition?

Answer (score 2):

[Acclimate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/acclimate) - 1 Become accustomed to a new climate or to new conditions

1.1 Biology respond physiologically or behaviorally to a change in a single environmental factor

"Although I have severe myopia, I've lived with it all my live and have thereore acclimated myself to the condition."

While this is the best word I was able to come up with, in my opinion, this word is less about resignation than it is about adaptation.  As such, it may not be a perfect match for your question.

You may want to consider instead: resigned.

[Resigned](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/resigned) - having accepted something unpleasant that one cannot do anything about.

You might also say you have "come to terms with it" or you have "accepted" your condition or "gotten used to it."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Lumberjack. I like acclimate, but, although the question may have been slightly unclear, the word I originally placed in that space was 'resigned'; I can't, of course, do anything about my myopia but I don't even find it unpleasant or at least not to a degree that makes me actively seek betterment of my eyesight.
I guess it's just difficult to verbalise how I feel about this condition... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the word that may be closer to "indiferent resignation" might be ***stoicism***. According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoicism):

> *noun*
>
> 1) the quality or behavior of a person who accepts what happens without complaining or showing emotion

So you could say that you have *"stoically adapted  to the situation"* or that you have *"stoically accepted the situation"*

Answer (score 0):

Stoic or stoicism. Adjective, next noun describes your thought process in one word. I have had lung removed and triple bypass . I not able to do what I want to and am resigned to my situation , however, I still have emotions about it. Always hope . Bless you

Comment: So your answer is ‘‘stoic or stoicism’’?   That answer has been given already.