# Term for 'Do not worry about what you cannot control'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am looking for a word or term [English or another language] that summarizes the concept:

'Do not worry about what you cannot control, only worry about what you can control'

Thanks!

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of [A word meaning an “indifferent resignation”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244732), but perhaps nor obviously enough that it should be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

This quote which became like a proverb might help:

> ***We can't direct the wind but we can adjust the sails.***

It is attributed to several authors, like for example, Thomas S. Monson.

It is not easy to find official definitions of this, but [this site](http://www.oldandwisemonk.com/2018/03/we-cant-direct-wind-but-we-can-adjust.html) says

> In this quote what Thomas S. Monson is trying to say is that most of
> the times we cannot control the situations but we can control our
> response to those situation which will decide our course in life.